# Recover my coin in utc file

Tags: wallets

I  have an UTC file from https://classicetherwallet.com this site .
But website is not reachable . how to recover my ETC COIN .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is a normal Ethereum wallet file. If so, you can use it with any other Ethereum wallet. You could try [myetherwallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) for example, use option "Keystore / JSON File".